# For loop input in BlueJ (infinite loop)

Tags: java, infinite-loop, bluej

I'm working on a project for school and am stumped at where I am at the moment. When I run my project, the VM seems to be stuck in a loop and will not load (A console should pop up allowing me to input characters for the CombinationLock class `setDigit()` method). I believe it has something to do with my for loop in my `Interface.java` class. If anyone could take a look and lead me in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

**Interface.java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Interface
{
    public static void main() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        CombinationLock combo = new CombinationLock();    

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String ltr = in.nextLine();
            combo.setDigit(ltr.charAt(0), i);
            System.out.println("Digit " + i + " has been set to " + ltr);
        }
    }
}
```

**CombinationLock.java**

```
public class CombinationLock
{
    String[] combo = new String[3];

    public CombinationLock() { }

    public boolean setDigit(char letter, int index) {
        if (Character.isDigit(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
        combo[index] = String.valueOf(letter);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean unlock(String combo) {
        if (combo.length() > 3) {
            return false; //Longer then it can be, not valid
        }

        char[] comboArray = combo.toCharArray();
        for (char c : comboArray) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                return false; //Contains numbers, not valid
            }
        }

        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (combo.charAt(i) != comboArray[i] && valid == true) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should be getting an index-out-of-bounds exception at `combo[index] = String.valueOf(letter);` because `combo` is a zero-length array.

Comment: Try `String[] combo = new String[3];` instead of `String[] combo = {};`.

Comment: I've edited the file to reflect those changes :) @BheshGurung

Comment: Check out my answer, it was not able to find your main method, because it has the wrong signature.

Comment: Hint: If you launch from the command line, you (typically) get a very helpful error message in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where my error was, using the BlueJ IDE one must output something to the console before it shows up and allows you to input data, therefore it never popped up as I never used `System.out.println` or `System.out.print`. After doing so, the console popped up and allowed me to input my data. Thanks you for all your suggestions and help!

Comment: Wasn't this giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as I mentioned?

Comment: Do you know how the IDE lauches the JVM, usually the JVM looks for the main method to invoke from where the application begins. Otherwise the main-class must be different.

Comment: When I run the class it allows me to select a method from that class to run. @BheshGurung

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized  `combo` array in `CombinationLock` class with length `0` as `String[] combo = {};`. This is cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you are calling `combo.setDigit(ltr.charAt(0), i);`. Please correct the initialization. I beleive you want to capture 3 inputs, in that case, please initialize  `combo` in `CombinationLock` with length 3 as below:

```
     String[] combo = new String[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is (the signature of the main method is wrong)

```
 public static void main() {
```

it should be

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the error, rather I've found the solution myself (I'll be posting what I did wrong). Thanks for your help :)